# Adicionar um item em um array que está dentro de outro array?

Tags: javascript

Minha dúvida é extremamente simples, adicionar um valor a um array que está dentro de outro.

```
var logDebug = ["value", [Adicionar itens aqui]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Só para complementar a resposta do Taffarel, se o **array secundário** não possuir posição fixa no **array principal** você pode fazer como no exemplo abaixo para não ter que fazer por exemplo **`logDebug[1]`**, fazendo um **for** para percorrer o array principal e comparando para ver se encontra um array com o método **[Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)**

```js
let logDebug= [1, 2, 3, 4, [], 5];

for(let i=0; i<logDebug.length; i++) {
  let array = Array.isArray(logDebug[i])
  
  if(array) logDebug[i].push('Qualquer coisa aqui!')
}

console.log(logDebug)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Tente este código:**

```js
var logDebug = ["value", []];
logDebug[1].push("novo valor 1");
logDebug[1].push("novo valor 2");
console.log(logDebug);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ou pode tentar tambem:

```js
let object = [1, 2, 3];
console.log('antes: ' + object);
item = 10;
object.push(item);
console.log('depois: ' + object);
```

**update**

```js
let logDebug = [];
logDebug.push({    
    value : []
});

let item = 'item';
logDebug[0].value.push(item);
console.log(logDebug);
```